# Number of connection running within certain period of time?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to capture number of connections or processes which is running on the prod server each 10 mins of interval? And MySQL version is 5.1.47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.processlist"
CONN_COUNT=`mysql ${MYSQL} -ANe"${SQL}"`
DT=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo "${DT} : Conenction Count = ${CONN_COUNT}" >> /var/log/messages
```

or

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global_status"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE variable_name='Threads_connected'"
CONN_COUNT=`mysql ${MYSQL} -ANe"${SQL}"`
DT=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo "${DT} : Conenction Count = ${CONN_COUNT}" >> /var/log/messages
```

Simply, put these lines in a script and crontab it every 10 min

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick, assuming your mysqld is listening on port 3306:

```
$ netstat -ant | grep ":3306" | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
50
```

You can put this in a script and execute every 10 minutes through cron.